# At what stage does WebView#setBackgroundResource take effect?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-resources

I am trying to do something very simple at the initialization of a WebView instance, such that the plain background color is replaced by an image (drawable) until some lengthy operation completes (which then loads a web page, of course). I am trying to accomplish this with:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

Android doesn't complain about anything **but it doesn't display the image**.

If I replace the above with:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#123456"));
```

The background color takes effect without any problem.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! That was quick (answering my own question):

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
myWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImage);
```

That's all I had to do. It works!